# how use serialize in jquery with my customize data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

i have this function:

```
function save_grad_form_one(id,a,b)
{

    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){$(this).show();});
    $("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){$(this).hide();});  

    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"student/class/ajax/save_grade.php", 
    data:($(":input").serialize(),{id:id ,a_one:a ,b_one:b}),
    success:function(data){
        if((data.result)=='true')
            alert(data.output);
            );
        }, 
    dataType:"json"});
    return false;

}
```

but in save_grade.php file the form values are empty. 
actuly my question is:

**can i use $(":input").serialize() and {id:id ,a_one:a ,b_one:b} in data part together?**
i used $(":input").serialize() alot and it works well always.

this is the first time i need to use them together. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters that you are receiving in the `save_grad_form_one(id,a,b)`
 function are the only ones which you need to post than you don't require serialize keyword.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Send the data in this format.

Comment: my form has Variable input name and fill by user.i can't use this format

Answer (score 0):

$(":input").serialize() returns you a string.

data:{serializedString:$(":input").serialize(),id:id ,a_one:a ,b_one:b},

Use this